# Finding a home for EF data access code that uses DI

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dry

Here's some code boiled down to a method that is called from a bunch of different locations:

```
private async Task<IQueryable<Book>> GetAllBooksWithPermissionToView(MyDbContext context)
{
    var currentUser = await _membershipService.GetCurrentUser<Publisher>(context);
    var books = context.Books.AsQueryable();

    var canViewAllBooks = _permissionChecker.DoesUserHavePermission(context, PermissionId.CanViewOtherPublishersBooks);
    if (!canViewAllBooks)
        books = books.WhereUserIsPublishingBook(currentUser.UserId);

    return books;
}
```

Here I'm retrieving `Book` entities that the current user has permissions to access.

**Where should this code live?**

I understand that often extension methods are frequently employed to help situations like this - in fact you'll see I'm already doing just that. In this case however, because it makes use of a couple of services (`IPermissionChecker` and `IMembershipService`), I would need to pass them through as arguments which seems a bit ugly.

The other obvious solution is to have a separate service just for retrieving these books. That service would hold the method above and would be injected in to places that need it. This also feels a bit wrong - perhaps because I find it hard to describe what the single responsibility of this service would be other than just "a place to put this method". I certainly don't want the service to turn in to a `PlaceToPutReusedQueriesService` and I also don't want to end up having heaps of individual services just for retrieving certain datasets. Is it valid to try and avoid these things?

Any ideas on how to proceed would be much appreciated.

Comment: It belongs on a Repository that depends on IPermissionChecker, IMembershipService and MyDbContext.  Your DI framework should supply all tree of them.  Whether this repository handles just Books or additional entities is up to you.

Comment: I would have thought that a Repository should only be for retrieving data and not be interested in business logic like this? Even knowing how to retrieve the logged in user seems like a violation of SRP. Would you suggest using the Repository exclusively for data access (the majority of which would be a useless abstraction of DbContext) or in addition to accessing MyDbContext directly (potentially confusing and not immediately obvious which one should be used).

Comment: Data access permissions are a closely related concern to data retrieval, and often are implemented in the back-end.

Comment: +1. With repository patterns things like authorization, soft-delete, (i.e. IsActive) and temporal type factors in data filtering are best contained in the repository for more consistency. Filtering for specific business logic is better left to business logic services/controllers.

Comment: @StevePy Thanks guys. I have been put off repositories due to the recent discussion about them being useless abstraction when you're working with EF's DbContext. Everything you're saying makes sense though, so I shall proceed!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to use the Query Object Pattern.

See the [article](https://codeopinion.com/query-objects-instead-of-repositories/) for a good explanation.